# Add some element to a variable it will be automaticated added to another variable

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm so confused

```js
updateList() {
    this.pendingApproval = [];
    this.agentCases = [];

    this.client.approvals_Get(token).subscribe(AResp => {
      const approvalResp = AResp;

      this.client.cases_GetAgentCases(token).subscribe(ACResp => {
        const agentCaseResp = ACResp;

        this.fieldsService.pendingRequests = approvalResp.result.cases;

        this.pendingApproval = approvalResp.result.cases;
        this.agentCases = agentCaseResp.cases;

        for (let i = 0; i < agentCaseResp.cases.length; i++) {
          if (!approvalResp.result.cases.find(x => x.caseId == agentCaseResp.cases[i].caseId)) {
            this.fieldsService.pendingRequests.push(agentCaseResp.cases[i]); //if i push element here i will find it in this.pendingApproval

            console.log("this.pendingApproval");
            console.log(this.pendingApproval);
          }
        }
      });
  });
  }
```

when i add some element to **this.fieldsService.pendingRequests** it will be automaticated added to **pendingApproval**

there is no event for handlling **pendingApproval** or **this.fieldsService.pendingRequests**

Comment: Unrelated, but try to use `forkJoin` or other similar RxJS operators when multiple observables are involved. Try to avoid nested subscriptions as much as possible.

Comment: thank you, always open to good advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this two lines, you are attaching same reference for `this.fieldsService.pendingRequests` and `this.pendingApproval`

```
this.fieldsService.pendingRequests = approvalResp.result.cases;

this.pendingApproval = approvalResp.result.cases;
```

You have to break the refernce by doing

```
this.fieldsService.pendingRequests = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(approvalResp.result.cases));

this.pendingApproval = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(approvalResp.result.cases));
```

See the below example to understand referencing,

In javascript objects are referenced. That means if you assign a object to one variable. And you change original object, then it would reflect in variable also

```js
var dummyObj = {
  a: 10
}
var firstReference = dummyObj;
var secondReference = dummyObj;
firstReference.a = 20;
console.log(secondReference.a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attaching same reference for `this.fieldsService.pendingRequests` and `this.pendingApproval`.

Just change the reference for one of the variable. You can do something like below with spread operator which will do the trick easiy.

```
this.pendingApproval = approvalResp.result.cases;
```

replace this line with below one

```
  this.pendingApproval = [...approvalResp.result.cases];
```

Hope this helps.. :)